# Need to send "High" and "Critical" priority only in email subject line itself

Tags: hooks

I'm using [Support Ticket System](https://www.drupal.org/project/support) module and I need to send ticket "High" and "Critical" priority along with subject line of an email. Can i do the same through coding part as i have tried from mail settings tab of support ticket system, help if anyone have an idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution might be to use [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) to modify the subject. As far as I have seen, the Support Ticket System uses `drupal_mail()` to send notifications, so this hook would be invoked.

Hope it helps,